# category permalinks

Tags: categories, menus, permalinks, pages, sub-menu

i am quite confused about the permalink stuff. So here is whats up... 
I have a page called tours as well as custom post type called mc_tours. At first i just changed page permalink to mydomain/mc_tours/  but then i wanted permalink to show just "Tours" so i assigned archive-mc_tours template to my tours page and changed permalink back to mydomain/tours/ (well when i click on single post permalink still changes to mydomain/mc_tours/post-name   no idea what to do with that... but id like it to be mydomain/tours/postname). And now i added categories as Tours page submenus. and when i click on a certain category the permalink changes from mydomain/tours/ to mydomain/category/category0-name, how can i set it that that permalink will be at least something like this mydomain/tours/category/category-name.  Ideal situation would be this: mydomain/tours/category-name... is there a way deal with this? or should i create pages for each category.

---

P.S i also want to have sidbar drowpdown category menu.

Comment: Please properly format your question. It is a mess and hard to read. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the rewrite argument when you register your post type:

```
$args = array(
    // [...]
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => "Tours" ),
);
register_post_type( mc_tours, $args );
```